# Geo, Date, and string matching elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an elasticsearch index called tweets,
I'm trying to filter these tweets by geo_distance, date, and optional string that might be passed. How should this query be like to meet my requirements

```
       "query":{
          "bool": {
             "must": [
                {
                   "term": {
                      "text": "ew"
                   }
                },
                {
                   "range": {
                      "date": {
                         "gte": "2009-05-31T02:30:45",
                         "lt": "now"
                      }
                   }
                },
                {
                   "filter": {
                      "geo_distance": {
                         "distance": "12km",
                         "pin.location": [-70, 40]
                      }
                   }
                }
              ]
           }
     }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the combination of [`filter` and `should` clause](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), to achieve your required result.

`filter` is used similar to logical AND operator, where the score of the query is ignored, and `should` is similar to logical OR operator.

Try out this below query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "2009-05-31T02:30:45",
              "lt": "now"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "12km",
            "pin.location": [
              -70,
              40
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "text": "ew"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```